# SQL-SERVER search array

Tags: sql, arrays, sql-server

Is  that a way to search array by using SQL?

```
SELECT Top 1 IVDTL.YourPONo
FROM IV
  INNER JOIN IVDTL
    ON IV.DOCKEY = IVDTL.DOCKEY
WHERE DocNo = /*array[0]*/
```

Any one have idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `Mysql` you can use [**`FIND_IN_SET`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

```
SELECT Top 1 IVDTL.YourPONo 
from IV 
INNER JOIN IVDTL
ON IV.DOCKEY = IVDTL.DOCKEY 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(DocNo ,'array[0]') > 0
```

**Update :**

For `SQL SERVER`

You need a split string function and split the values in array to individual rows. Then it can be used in `IN` clause

For **`SQL SERVER 2016`**

you can use `STRING_SPLIT` function

```
SELECT Top 1 IVDTL.YourPONo
FROM IV
  INNER JOIN IVDTL
    ON IV.DOCKEY = IVDTL.DOCKEY
WHERE DocNo in (select value from STRING_SPLIT('array[0]',',')
```

---

For any thing less than **`SQL SERVER 2016`**

use any one of the methods from below excellent article [Split strings the right way – or the next best way](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings)

Here is one way using `XML`

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitStrings_XML
(
   @List       NVARCHAR(MAX),
   @Delimiter  NVARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
   RETURN 
   (  
      SELECT Item = y.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'nvarchar(4000)')
      FROM 
      ( 
        SELECT x = CONVERT(XML, '<i>' 
          + REPLACE(@List, @Delimiter, '</i><i>') 
          + '</i>').query('.')
      ) AS a CROSS APPLY x.nodes('i') AS y(i)
   );
```

After creating the function use the function in your query

```
SELECT Top 1 IVDTL.YourPONo
FROM IV
  INNER JOIN IVDTL
    ON IV.DOCKEY = IVDTL.DOCKEY
WHERE DocNo in (select value from SplitStrings_XML('array[0]',',')
```

Comment: It show ===== 'FIND_IN_SET' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: @ChengWan Here is the `Mysql` official documentation link http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set

Comment: @ChengWan - Are you sure that you are using `Mysql`

Comment: @ChengWan -yep.. You are using `SQL SERVER`

Comment: sorry bro, i'm new in this field.. totally have no idea.

Comment: Hey bro now it show ===== Invalid object name 'STRING_SPLIT'.

Comment: @ChengWan Just run this `Select @@version` and tell me what it returned. You didnt read my answer properly for sure.

Comment: sorry bro didn't read finish. mine is 2008. where to create xml? save at where?

Comment: @ChengWan - Check the answer for anything less than `SQL SERVER 2016`